# Liquibase loading data from csv

Tags: java, database, liquibase

I want to load an entire column of my PostgreSql table with data from csv file but when I do that I get an exception saying that the primary key of my table should not be null. It looks like Liquibase is creating new rows to insert the data. Is there a way to load the data in existing rows ?

```
DatabaseChangeLog dbChangeLog = new DatabaseChangeLog();
Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(dbChangeLog, new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database);
ChangeSet loadChangeSet = new ChangeSet(id + "", "nasri", false, false, "", "", "", liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog());

LoadDataChange loadDataChange = new LoadDataChange();
loadDataChange.setTableName(key);
loadDataChange.setChangeSet(loadChangeSet);
loadDataChange.setResourceAccessor(new FileSystemResourceAccessor());

String path = context.getBundle().getVersion() + "." + key + "." + columnKey + "." + targetFieldKey + ".csv";
loadDataChange.setFile(path);

loadDataChange.setSchemaName("public");

LoadDataColumnConfig columnConfig = new LoadDataColumnConfig();
columnConfig.setName(targetFieldKey);
columnConfig.setType("String");
loadDataChange.addColumn(columnConfig);
loadChangeSet.addChange(loadDataChange);
liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog().addChangeSet(loadChangeSet);
liquibase.update("");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class thats called: [LoadUpdateDataChange](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/change/core/LoadUpdateDataChange.java)

The description says:

> Loads or updates data from a CSV file into an existing table. Differs from loadData by issuing a SQL batch that checks for the existence of a record. If found, the record is UPDATEd, else the record is INSERTed. Also, generates DELETE statements for a rollback.

Looks like it should do what you are looking for (I have not used this myself though).

Answer (score 0):

To update records, LoadUpdateDataChange is not working for me. Its always trying to insert new records.It won't update existing records.

If want to update existing records, you should use  like below.

```
<update tableName="someTable">

   <column name="update_column_name" value="updated value" />

   <where> primaryKey = condition</where>

</update>
```